# Controller method to do fuzzy search for companies

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, search, controller

I would like some help to clean up this action, especially from `@companies` and downward. The comments should be enough to explain :)

```rb
def search
  @query = params[:query]
  unless @query.blank?
    @query.strip!
    #Get tags with fuzzy match
    tags = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%").pluck(:name)

    #Get vouchers with these tags
    @vouchers = Voucher.tagged_with(tags, :any => true)

    #Get companies with these tags, and add their vouchers to the list
    @companies = Company.tagged_with(tags, :any => true)
    @companies.each do |company|
      #Because can't merge with nil. Can this be re-written?
      if @vouchers.empty?
        @vouchers = company.vouchers
      else
        @vouchers.merge(company.vouchers)
      end
    end

    #Get every voucher's category. Can this be re-written?
    @categories = []
    @vouchers.each do |voucher|
      @categories << voucher.categories
    end
    #Because can't call .flatten on nil
    if @categories.any?
      #Need to flatten because the array will contain an arrays of categories [[],[],[]]
      @categories.flatten!.uniq # I don't really want .flatten.uniq in the view, or?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misjudged what you're going for, this should work (it's not pretty though, I'm sure there's an even better way)

```
def search
  @query = params[:query].try(:strip) # strip here instead

  unless @query.blank?
    tags = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%").pluck(:name)
    @companies  = Company.tagged_with(tags, :any => true).includes(:vouchers) # eager load vouchers
    @vouchers   = [
      Voucher.tagged_with(tags, :any => true),
      companies.map(&:vouchers)
    ].flatten.uniq
    @categories = @vouchers.map(&:categories).uniq
  else
    # you need something here, by the way...
  end
end
```

If you don't need each of the collections in the search results, but only need the `categories`, you should probably add this to the `Company` model

```
has_many :categories, :through => :vouchers
```

then you can do

```
def search
  @query = params[:query].strip # strip here instead

  unless @query.blank?
    tags = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{@query}%").pluck(:name)
    vouchers  = Voucher.tagged_with(tags, :any => true).includes(:categories)
    companies = Company.tagged_with(tags, :any => true).includes(:categories)

    @categories = [vouchers, companies].flatten.map(&:categories).flatten.uniq
  end
end
```

However, I'd think about restructuring the database if possible, to avoid the mix of 1st and 2nd order associations.

Comment: I'm using your first example. Exactly the type of refactoring I was looking for. But watch out, you can't call .strip on params that are nil

Comment: @Frexuz Ah, of course you're right about that. Wasn't thinking. But it's an excellent chance to use ActiveSupport's `try` method. I've updated my code

Comment: Yes, I went with `try` instead. Just love that method :)